# SQL to get the population percentage with respect to the state for each city

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL table.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```sql
    CREATE TABLE test (
      id INT,
      city TEXT,
      state TEXT,
      population INT
    );
    INSERT INTO test (id, city, state, population) VALUES (1, "kol", "wb", 40);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (2, "siliguri", "wb", 30);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (3, "malda", "wb", 20);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (4, "darjeeling", "wb", 10);
    
    INSERT INTO test (id, city, state, population) VALUES (5, "lucknow", "up", 70);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (6, "meerut", "up", 56);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (7, "noida", "up", 78);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (8, "kanpur", "up", 42);
    
    INSERT INTO test (id, city, state, population) VALUES (9,  "mumbai", "maharashtra", 63);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (10, "nagpur", "maharashtra",  45);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (11,  "pune", "maharashtra", 52);
    INSERT INTO test (id,  city, state, population) VALUES (12, "navi mumbai", "maharashtra",  42);
```

**Query #1**

```sql
SELECT city, population, K.state, population/totPop*100 
  FROM test JOIN 
     (SELECT P.state, P.totPop FROM 
        (SELECT state, SUM(population) AS totPop 
        FROM test 
     GROUP BY state) 
  AS P) 
AS K ON test.state=K.state;
```

| city | population | state | population/totPop*100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mumbai | 63 | maharashtra | 31.1881 |
| nagpur | 45 | maharashtra | 22.2772 |
| pune | 52 | maharashtra | 25.7426 |
| navi mumbai | 42 | maharashtra | 20.7921 |
| lucknow | 70 | up | 28.4553 |
| meerut | 56 | up | 22.7642 |
| noida | 78 | up | 31.7073 |
| kanpur | 42 | up | 17.0732 |
| kol | 40 | wb | 40.0000 |
| siliguri | 30 | wb | 30.0000 |
| malda | 20 | wb | 20.0000 |
| darjeeling | 10 | wb | 10.0000 |

---

**Can anyone help write the query without any JOINs**

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I did that with join..but I have no clue how to do it without join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.city, t1.state, t1.population,  
       100 * t1.population / (SELECT SUM(t2.population) FROM test t2 WHERE t2.state = t1.state) pop_percent
FROM test t1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6b7bbc3b76faee551525ad1e570fb3bf).

Comment: Awesome...Thanks. can you please point me to any resource from where I can learn the `correlated subquery` better with some examples?

Comment: @MayukhSarkar for subqueries and correlated subqueries: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/ and https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php